# Fondo de pantalla arroja: Error code: 393238

Tags: android-studio

Me da este error

> Error code: 393238,  Buffer overflow, no available space

al meter un fondo de pantalla en mi aplicación Android en Android Studio, ¿alguien sabe por qué?

El error:

```
06-05 19:58:27.175 1532-2324/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-05 19:58:27.175 3141-24557/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-05 19:58:27.178 3141-24557/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-05 19:58:27.178 3141-24557/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-05 19:58:27.178 3141-24557/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@620f2ed
06-05 19:58:27.180 3141-3141/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
06-05 19:58:27.185 3141-24557/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@620f2ed
06-05 19:58:27.185 3141-23718/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
06-05 19:58:27.185 3141-23718/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
06-05 19:58:27.185 3141-3372/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
06-05 19:58:27.185 3141-23718/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6) 
06-05 19:58:27.186 3141-23718/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
06-05 19:58:27.188 3141-3141/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
06-05 19:58:27.188 3141-3141/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
06-05 19:58:27.188 3141-24459/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
06-05 19:58:31.422 24683-24683/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
06-05 19:58:31.471 24683-24683/? W/app_process: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-05 19:58:31.494 24683-24683/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-05 19:58:31.502 24683-24683/? I/app_process: System.exit called, status: 0
06-05 19:58:31.502 24683-24683/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
06-05 19:58:31.731 1386-1386/? E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.example.dam2_alejandroexpo.proyecto_dam2_aec': Connection refused
06-05 19:58:32.122 24702-24702/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
06-05 19:58:32.181 24702-24702/? W/app_process: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-05 19:58:32.195 3141-3141/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
    #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
06-05 19:58:32.196 3141-3141/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
06-05 19:58:32.197 3141-3141/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
06-05 19:58:32.205 3141-23718/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
06-05 19:58:32.206 3141-24557/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@69b7e2b
06-05 19:58:32.212 1532-24713/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa0b83900 tid=24713 ready to run
06-05 19:58:32.218 1532-2324/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-05 19:58:32.218 1532-2324/? D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xa54303a0, size=4194304)
        0: 0xa54303b0 | 0x00000000 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        1: 0xa54303d0 | 0x000200E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        2: 0xa5430570 | 0x000401C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        3: 0xa5430700 | 0x000602A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        4: 0xa54306c0 | 0x00080380 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        5: 0xa527c530 | 0x000A0460 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        6: 0xa527c6b0 | 0x000C0540 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        7: 0xa54307d0 | 0x000E0620 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        8: 0xa5430980 | 0x00100700 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        9: 0xa5430b60 | 0x001207E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       10: 0xa5430d30 | 0x001408C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       11: 0xa527ca40 | 0x001609A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       12: 0xa5430ee0 | 0x00180A80 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       13: 0xa547e070 | 0x001A0B60 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       14: 0xa527cbf0 | 0x001C0C40 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       15: 0xa527cdd0 | 0x001E0D20 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       16: 0xa527cf50 | 0x00200E00 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       17: 0xa547e1b0 | 0x00220EE0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       18: 0xa547e370 | 0x00240FC0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       19: 0xa547e500 | 0x002610A0 | 0x000200E0 | A
```

Comment: Expo, te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: ¿Que estas realizando? porque  no agregas un poco de tu código para que esta pregunta sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Añade el siguiente permiso al Manifests.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: ¿Que ayuda el agregar el permiso RECORD_AUDIO ?